# How to combine multiple columns as one and format with custom strings?

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT id, <X> AS name FROM `table`
```

Basically `<X>` is a combination of
lastname + ', ' + firstname

example would be

```
   id | name        |
   2  | Smith, Bob  |
   3  | Jones, Susy |
```

This is just an example, I don't really want to combine names so simple.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

What about the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function?

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(lastname, ', ', firstname) AS name FROM `table`;
```

If you are going to concatenate many fields, you could also consider the [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function, where the first argument is the separator for the rest of the arguments, which is added between the strings to be concatenated:

```
SELECT id, 
       CONCAT_WS(',', field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4) list
FROM   `table`;
```

Comment: this what i was looking for. but what is the cost to this though, does this weigh in heavey on MySQL or it's not of a problem to be concerned about?

Answer (score 3):

use [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) like :

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(lastname, ' , ', firstname) AS name FROM `table`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 

CONCAT('https://example.com/estimation/create?pId=',task_p_id,'&estId=',task_est_id) as live_url,

CONCAT('http://stage.example.com/estimation/create?pId=',task_p_id,'&estId=',task_est_id) as stage_url 

FROM `ls_task` LEFT JOIN `ls_estimation` ON est_id=task_est_id LEFT JOIN `ls_project` ON p_id=task_p_id limit 10
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

Example of getting all the column names of a table separated by comma:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.`COLUMN_NAME`) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` c
WHERE c.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = "DB_NAME" AND c.`TABLE_NAME`="TABLE_NAME"
```

Output:

```
column_name_1,column_name_2,column_name_3,column_name_4,...
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question.