# How to use CONCAT_WS() in Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

To combine multiple columns as one,
[I found one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757723/how-to-combine-multiple-columns-as-one-and-format-with-custom-strings?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

```
SELECT id,CONCAT_WS(',', field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4) list
FROM  `table`;
```

This query working fine in SQL but it gives me error in HQL:
Error is .

### (java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode )

please help me to find out what wrong i did, help me to know how to use CONCAT_WS() IN HQL

below how i written my HQL query

```
SELECT C1._URI,C1.HEALTH_FACILITY,C1.DISTRICT,CONCAT_WS(',', C1.BLOCKS_OF_BHUBRI, C1.BLOCKS_OF_GOLAGHAT, C1.BLOCKS_OF_HAILAKANDI) as Block_name
FROM GapAnalysisWashInHealthFacilitiesCore C1
```

any help will appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT_WS` is a function specific to mySql. HQL is a generic language and not aware of native SQL functions and syntax. If you really need the function, then you should use Hibernate's API for native SQL.

```
Session session = ...;
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("
    SELECT id,CONCAT_WS(',', field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4) Block_name FROM `table`");
List result = query.list();
```

Then you may like to have a look at [Result Transformers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) to get result as list of `GapAnalysisWashInHealthFacilitiesCore` objects.